# Something I came across in a movie 你说它真它就真说它假

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, expressions, idioms

I came across this in a Chinese television show, which I would like some help to translate.

你说它真它就真，说它假它就假，它是真真假假假假真真谁也弄不明白.

The first part I do understand. It means: "If you say it is real then it is real, if you say it is fake then it is fake".

But the second part of the sentence I can't make much sense of.

Is there some brilliant mind out there that can?

Comment: google 真真假假假假真真 -> 28,500 results

see e.g.真真假假假假真真-----全乱了人民网强国社区(http://bbs.people.com.cn)
　　北京人天天吃肉馅包子，谁知某一天被告知肉馅包子是假的，肉馅都是用费纸箱加火碱炮制而成的，于是全国舆论对小商贩大肆讨伐，可不几天峰回路转，不知为什么，此新闻被证明是假新闻，于是对制造假新闻者又进行了更大规模的讨伐，就这样我们现在陷于真真假假假假真真的迷魂阵中。
"confusing;confusion"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

你说它真它就真，说它假它就假， 它是真真假假假假真真谁也弄不明白.

```
You claim it's true and as truth it is. 
You declare it's faulty as falsehood is should be. 
Is it true or false, go figure!
```

One not so elegant translation would be

```
if you say A, and I supposed to believe it as A and when you say about
the same thing but this time it is B, and I supposed to believe it is
B, so is it A or B???? what do I know???
```

The concept is quite similar to an old saying "to swear black is white." Or you can use the biblical reference on Mark 11:24 "Therefore I say to you, all things for which you pray and ask, believe that you have received them, and they will be granted you."  Or if you stretch this more, "Cogito ergo sum," which is the Latin philosophical proposition by René Descartes, as in English "I think, therefore I am."

It’s the true pseudo-profound bullshit! ref: Judgment and Decision Making, Vol. 10, No. 6, November 2015, pp. 549–563 
http://journal.sjdm.org/15/15923a/jdm15923a.pdf

Comment: it really is awesome that Stackoverflow allows me to get in touch with the brilliant minds out there!

Comment: Are you able to put a short English line to what the point of this is?

Comment: It's a cute and hazy way to say "don't bullshi* me!" In the same time, by having it in a tongue twister manner projects the idea in a friendly way.